# CUDA-GDB prints memory content using int format even though it should be float

Tags: debugging, types, gdb, cuda-gdb

In a CUDA C project, I have a pointer to float inside a structure called "p".
It is a pointer to device memory and it is called "p->deviceOutput". I am using CUDA-GDB to check the content of this pointer during execution: when I try to print it this is what happens:

```
(gdb) p *p->deviceOutput
$1 = 0
```

As you can see the printing returns something that looks like an int, definitely not a float.
I am really sure the pointer is a pointer to float so I am really confused by this behaviour.
Specifying the float format does not help:

```
(gdb) p/f *p->deviceOutput
$2 = 0
```

Actually I get the same behaviour using GDB as well.
I am working on Ubuntu 14.10 and my code was compiled with nvcc using -O0 and -g options.

Can anybody please explain what is going on and what should I do to inspect this memory location correctly? Thanks

Comment: Does `(gdb) printf "%f\n", *p->deviceOutput` print what you expect?

Comment: Yes, thanks: this command prints "0.000000", which is not what I expected from the code but at least it shows a float formatting.

Answer (score 1):

gdb uses the `g` format specifier to printf (internally) when printing floating point values.  Here's the interesting part of the description of `g` from the [man page for printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf):

> Trailing zeros are removed from the fractional part of the result; a
>   decimal point appears only if it is followed by at least one digit.

So you're getting 0 because the floating point value is 0, and the `g` format specifier (used by gdb) prints an exact 0 without a decimal point, or any trailing 0's.

You can check that your variable is of type float using the `ptype` command, like this:

```
(gdb) ptype p->deviceOutput
```

Comment: Thanks, this explains the unexpected behaviour. The ptype command returns "type = float *". The printf command returns "0.000000", which confirms your statements.